# SATA SSD Latency using ioping

Tags: ssd, sata, latency

SATA SSDs are expected to have latency in the range of a few hundred microseconds, but when I measure it using `ioping`, the latency is around 2ms.

Is there any reason for such high latency in SATA SSDs?

- SSD: Samsung SSD 850
- OS: Linux
- Command:

```
ioping -D -c 20
```

- One of results:

> 4 KiB <<< . (ext4 /dev/sdb): request=10 time=2.00 ms

Comment: Ok thats one of the results. What are the other results, or what's the end line showing min/avg/max/mdev ? It's not abnormal to some single ioping requests to show up being several ms.

Comment: TBH, I have same weird experience using the Windows version when comparing NVMe SSD vs external hard drive (!), which makes me somewhat doubt the test. Test using HD Sentinel gives much more realistic values.